# Python plot after string

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot data from .dat file. But this .dat file starts with string. For example, My file includes col 1 col 2 col 3 and I want to read under the col 3 data. I want skip two rows because they have string and wanna read only under col 3. How can  skip the strings?. If we accept the data is 5x3 data so that I will only plot (3:5,3) for col3. How can I do? I share a code and this is only working If I remove string.

```
  #-------input.dat---------
  #   x        y     z
  # col 1    col 2  col 3
  # 3          5      5
  # 5          6      4
  # 7          7      3
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np
  import pylab as pl


  data = open('input.dat')
  lines = data.readlines()
  data.close()
  x1=[]
  for line in lines:
    p= line.split()
    x1.append(float(p[3]))

  xv=np.array(x1)
  plt.plot(xv)
  plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already importing `numpy`, you could use [`np.genfromtext`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) here to make things a lot simpler, since it has the option `skip_header` which tells it how many header rows to skip.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('input.dat', skipheader=2)
xv = data[:, 2]

plt.plot(xv)
plt.show()
```

Or, if you only need to read in column 3:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xv = np.genfromtxt('input.dat', skipheader=2, usecols=(2,))

plt.plot(xv)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the header lines:

```
for line in lines[2:]:
    p= line.split()
    x1.append(float(p[3]))
```

This leaves out the first two lines of you input.dat